# i want to update only single row column value with rollback commit

Tags: list, linq, if-statement, datacontext, rollback

i want to update only single row column value with rollback commit but when i create table object inside if and pass to insertonsubmit it gives me error,plz help me how can i solve this

```
var challan = dataContext.Purchase_Challans.Where(t => t.Challan_ID == Convert.ToInt64(ViewState["challanid"]) && t.Company_ID == Convert.ToInt32(Session["CompanyId"])).Select(t => t).ToList();
                        if (challan.Any())
                        {
                            challan.ToList()[0].Inv_DocumentId = dmsPurchaseInvoice.Document_ID;
                            dataContext.Purchase_Challans.InsertOnSubmit()
                            dataContext.SubmitChanges();
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be helpful to know more details about the error, but I assume it's because you tell the dataContext to insert an entity that you just retrieved (whereas you want to update it).

Also the code you posted does not even compile and is full of questionable code, like `challan.ToList()` where it already is a list, or parsing strings inside a delegate.

That said, this code is more straightforward and more likely to work (but to be honest I didn't test it):

```
var challanId = Convert.ToInt64(ViewState["challanid"]);
var companyId = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["CompanyId"]);
var challan = dataContext.Purchase_Challans.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Challan_ID == challanId && t.Company_ID == companyId);
if (challan != null)
{
    challan.Inv_DocumentId = dmsPurchaseInvoice.Documet_Id;
    dataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.It's work for me.i was think that if i use direct "submitchanges()" without insertonsubmit then rollback its not work.but it now work thanks for this.

Comment: As I'm hunting for more reputation, could you then please mark the answer as the accepted one and vote it up? Thanks.